# mount options for bindmount

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

Due to some complex requirements, I had to put the following two lines in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/xvdg1        /srv/storage  ext4  $OPTIONS1      0 2
/srv/storage/dir  /var/opt/dir  none  bind,$OPTIONS2 0 0
```

Now my question is: Do I have to re-list all mount options $OPTIONS1 in $OPTIONS2, or will the second line (the bindmount line) inherit the options of $OPTIONS1?

FYI, here is the actual options used in $OPTIONS1:

```
rw,auto,async,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=0,delalloc
```

---

**ETA**: actually I use `UUID=...` instead of `/dev/xvdg1`, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "maybe", because it depends on which option you're passing, and what it is enforced by. If the options you are passing are strictly superblock flags, you don't need to relist the options as part of the bind mount. If the options you are passing contain a vfsmount flag, then yes, you need to relist the vfsmount flags. You can think of "superblock flag" as meaning that it's part of the underlying filesystem, and "vfsmount flag" as meaning that it's part of the kernel (although this is not technically true, since the kernel is the one enforcing both in reality).

You need to do this with arguments like `noexec`, `nodev`, or `nosuid`, because they apply per-filesystem (see [this thread](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0110.1/1712.html) on the kernel mailing list for some good information).

```
$ truncate -s 10M container
$ mkfs.ext4 container
$ mkdir mountpoint binded
$ sudo mount -o loop container mountpoint
$ sudo chown "$EUID" mountpoint
$ sudo mount -o bind mountpoint binded
$ cat > mountpoint/script << 'EOF'
> #!/bin/bash
> echo "This works."
> EOF
$ chmod +x mountpoint/script
$ binded/script 
This works.
$ sudo mount -o remount,noexec mountpoint
$ binded/script
This works.
$ mountpoint/script
bash: mountpoint/script: Permission denied
```

Note that despite being the same script, `noexec` is only being enforced per-filesystem. This is because it's a vfsmount flag, not a superblock flag -- that is, it's a functionality of the kernel, not the filesystem.

Note how the output of `mount` for the two mountpoints looks like after this, and that `noexec` did not carry over:

```
$ mount
[...]
/tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/container on /tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/mountpoint type ext4 (noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
/tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/container on /tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/binded type ext4 (relatime,data=ordered)
```

If we remount the bind itself with `noexec`, however, this works as expected:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,noexec binded
$ mount
[...]
/tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/container on /tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/mountpoint type ext4 (noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
/tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/container on /tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/binded type ext4 (noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Options which are underlying filesystem attributes, however, generally do not need to be done again on the bind mount (and they will probably raise an error, since many of the supported options are defined by the filesystem). A simple one to demonstrate is `ro`, the read-only option, but this applies to other superblock flags as well.

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,ro mountpoint
$ > mountpoint/test
bash: mountpoint/test: Read-only file system
$ > binded/test
bash: binded/test: Read-only file system
```

Note that this time, the flag carries over automatically:

```
$ mount
[...]
/tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/container on /tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/mountpoint type ext4 (ro,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
/tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/container on /tmp/tmp.hoiHQYPEFX/binded type ext4 (ro,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a very informative and educative answer! Marking yours as 'the' answer :)